# Is it possible to create cyclic bins using xhistogram?

Tags: python-xarray, binning

I'm trying to bin data based on local time. I want a bin centered on 00 local time, but that would require the left bin edge to be greater in value than the right bin edge. For example, if the bin width is 2 hours, a bin centered on 00 local time would need to be (x > 23) and (x < 01) for example. This is different than say a bin centered on 03, which would be more simply (02 < x < 04).

I'm wondering if xhistogram has this capability or if I need to do something clever to make it work.

Comment: as far as I can tell this isn't currently possible in xhistogram. note that xhistogram is *very* new. you may have noticed all the notes-to-self about lists vs. bin specs in the [tutorial](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) :)

Comment: I think the way to enable this would be to allow the user to provide a more flexible mapping from input value ranges to output bins. I think that's a great idea, and if you wanted to propose it as a [feature request](https://github.com/xgcm/xhistogram/issues) I'm sure the team would welcome it. That said, while it's a powerful package, the user and maintainer list is relatively limited, and you might not see this implemented any time soon unless you wanted to contribute it yourself (which would be awesome!)